# How to draw multiple "stacks" in single column in WPF

Tags: wpf

I need to create a view that is able to show dynamic data similar to the mockup image below. Each row can be considered consisting of three parts, where the left and right part consist of a variable number of rectangles, and the middle part is a number. The number in the middle will remain the same once the row has been added, whereas the left and right part will be dynamically updated (width of rectangles grow and new rectangles are added) as time goes by and more and more data is processed.

The width of each rectangle needs to be calculated based on the number that the rectangle represents, e.g., one pixel for every "10th value / amount / volume".

My question is, what is a good approach to solving this problem? Is there some Brush in WPF that would solve this issue in an easy manner? Should a dynamic number of rectangles for each side on each row be used? If so, how can the position and size be calculated for each rectangle?

Performance is not really an issue (although I would love input on things to consider).

[image]

Comment: You can multi color fill any primitive by using the LinearGradiantBrush. The trick is to make your steps double gradient stops. I.e. 0 = Blue, 0.75 = Blue, 0.75 = Red, 1 = Red.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Oh. If that gets rid of the "linear" of the brush it would solve a lot of things. Will try it out. Got to say, sounds like this should have been a reply and not a comment, so that I could mark it as an answer in case it work as I hope it will.

Comment: Ok, I made it an answer. Yes, it works. It's actually documented by Microsoft somewhere... I use it all the time. You can do some pretty tricky things with it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multi color fill any primitive by using the LinearGradiantBrush. The trick is to make your steps double gradient stops. I.e. 0 = Blue, 0.75 = Blue, 0.75 = Red, 1 = Red. This will give you hard color transitions and not have any gradient effect.